# :: *: expects a number as 1st argument, given (lambda (a1) ...)

Tags: racket

We need to calculate the "cpu performance per euro" using a function. When we run the code, it returns the error: `:: *: expects a number as 1st argument, given (lambda (a1) ...)` Why is the argument `cpu-clock` a lambda function and not a number? How can we correct it? Here is our code (This is not the whole code, but this is the necessary part):

```
(define-struct cpu (name socket clock cores price))
(define-struct gpu (name gflops memory connectors price))
(define-struct mainboard (name socket connectors price))


;; A list of cpus
(define cpus
  (list
   (make-cpu 'R9-3900X 'AM4 3.8 12 512.99)
   (make-cpu 'R3-1200 'AM4 3.1 4 49.55)
   (make-cpu 'R3-3200G 'AM4 3.6 4 92.99)
   (make-cpu 'R5-3600 'AM4 3.6 6 195.9)
   (make-cpu 'R7-3700X 'AM4 3.6 8 328.9)
   (make-cpu 'i3-9100F 'LGA1151v2 3.6 4 75.65)
   (make-cpu 'i5-9400F 'LGA1151v2 2.9 6 143.49)
   (make-cpu 'i7-9700F 'LGA1151v2 3 8 329.99)
  )
)

;; Type: 
;; Returns: 
(define (cpu-performance-per-euro cpu)
  (/ (round (* (/ (* cpu-clock cpu-cores) cpu-price) 1000)) 1000)
)

(check-expect (cpu-performance-per-euro (make-cpu 'R9-3900X 'AM4 3.8 12 512.99)) 0.089)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cpu-clock`, `cpu-cores`, `cpu-price`, etc., are functions, not values. They take a `cpu` structure and return the corresponding values. So you should change the function in this way:

```
(define (cpu-performance-per-euro cpu)
  (/ (round (* (/ (* (cpu-clock cpu) (cpu-cores cpu)) (cpu-price cpu)) 1000)) 1000))
```